# Call timer starts counting right after callee accept a call

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, voip, callkit

I'm integrating calls in my app. In CallKit documentation  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit there is a text:

> After the call is connected, the system calls the provider(_:perform:) method of the provider delegate. In your implementation, the delegate is responsible for configuring an AVAudioSession and calling fulfill() on the action when finished.

And code snippet:

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
    // configure audio session
    action.fulfill()
}
```

And about *fulfill()* method:

> You should only call this method from the implementation of a CXProviderDelegate method.

So as I understood, we should call action.fulfill() immediately, after callee accepts a call.

Problem: When device is locked, call timer on native CallKit screen starts counting, but connection is not established yet.

Question: How can I call action.fulfill() or start the timer on the locked  CallKit screen, when connection will be established. Can I control this timer label on locked screen somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It is expected that you call the answering logic in this delegate callback

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
    // configure audio session
    // Performing call answering logic
    // Call action to fulfill after answering logic is finished
    action.fulfill()
}
```

I am using PJSIP for VoIP calls and this is how my answering logic looks like this

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {

    guard let call = CallList.sharedInstance().call(withUUID: action.callUUID.uuidString) else {
        action.fail()
        return
    }

    CallAudio.configureAudioSession()

    // Answer call (signal Pjsua)
    Pjsua2Wrapper.sharedInstance()?.answerCall(withCallUUID: call.callUUID, completion: { error in
        if error != nil {
            // we have error on answer call
            action.fail()
        } else {
            action.fulfill()
        }
    })
}
```

Answer call's completion handler is called when answering is done, so the timer will start when the call is connected.

### **EDIT**

Sound issue with PJSIP

If using PJSIP, you need to stop the audio I/O when PJSIP is initialized, like so (it is C++):

```
enableSoundDevice( false );
```

And when call is answered, `CallKit` will respond with func `provider(_:didActivate:)`. That is where you need to activate the PJSIP sound device in order to have the sound.

This is the example from my code:

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didActivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
    // Start call audio I/O once CallKit activates AVAudioSession
    Pjsua2Wrapper.sharedInstance()?.enableSoundDevice(true)
}
```

And, ofcourse, when call is ended or set on hold, when `CallKit` responds with `provider(_:didDeactivate:)`, you disable PJSIP sound device again and that's it

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didDeactivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
    // Stop call audio IO
    Pjsua2Wrapper.sharedInstance()?.enableSoundDevice(false)
}
```

Comment: Tried this, it's worked for the timer, but somehow I can't hear anything after connection established. Did you have problems with audio?

Comment: Yes, I had problems with audio. If you are using PJSIP, there is a simple solution, in code, where PJSIP is initialized, you just need to stop audio I/O. In my code, it looks like this: 
    enableSoundDevice( false );

Comment: And remember that you need to enable the sound device (start audio I/O) when CXProviderDelegate activates the audio session with, func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didActivate audioSession: AVAudioSession)